# how to find the php file in my joomla website

Tags: joomla, components, customization

I have joomla website with an external component installed. I want to make some customizations to the third party component but I can't find the php file. I can see the buttons and other elements using firebug of firefox but I can't find the source files. 
Please give me any hint.

Comment: `components/com_NAME/views/VIEW_NAME/tmpl/default.php`

Answer (score 1):

The source files are in a folder named like "com_componentname", You can find it in the "components" folder.

If the component is well build you should find one folder named "view" in the main folder of your component. In each subfolder there's a folder named "tmpl", the file that you search is in one of this folders.

You also can try to do "ctrl+shift+f" for search in a folder with your code editor.

Comment: Thanx MOWebCreation, I do make searches even text searches in the source code folder in my joomla root, but I can't find it.

Comment: What is the component name and what do you change ??

Answer (score 1):

Your component may use a template override, please check: /templates/your_template/html/component_name/

Comment: Thanx Emmanuel, I couln't find it cause of the template overriding.